# Can I make a subview fill the view in its size?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view, say a red rectangle, and I have a subview of it, a green rectangle, all added programmatically.

Now, how can I make a green rectangle fill the whole red rectangle in width and height without getting current size of the screen, so that when red rectangle resizes on screen rotation, the green one resizes automatically too?

Comment: You can make use of [`Auto Layout`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/).

Answer (score 4):

```
let redView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 350))
redView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
redView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
view.addSubview(redView)

let greenView = UIView(frame: redView.bounds)
greenView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
redView.addSubview(greenView)

greenView.autoresizingMask = redView.autoresizingMask
```

Comment: autoresizingMask did it for me. Note it's .flexibleWidth and .flexibleHeight in Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `layoutSubviews()` method of Red Rectangle. Inside the layout, just reassign the red rectangle frame to the green Rectangle frame. This would make the frame resize and refill on orientation as well.

This is merely an example code for reference.

```
class RedRect:UIView {

    void layoutSubviews(){

        greenRect.frame = bounds

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Visual Format Auto Layout` like below where `self == YOUR_GREEN_RECT`

```
guard let superview = self.superview else {
    return
}

self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
superview.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[subview]-0-|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["subview": self]))
superview.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[subview]-0-|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["subview": self]))
```

Or just using `Autoresizingmask`

```
self.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class RedRect:UIView {

    void layoutSubviews(){

        greenRect.frame = bounds

    }

}
```

should be frame = bounds

Comment: thank you for the answer. I will edit it.

However, you should provide that in comments, not as an answer itself, sir.

Comment: Sry, I don't have enough REPUTATION to comment on your post